# How to open a running instance of a program in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, process

When I try to open VeraCrypt I get this error: `VeraCrypt is already running.`. How can I open the running instance?

Comment: it really depends on your own definition of *"Open the running instance"* ;  looking at logs ? check what file it has openned ? etc...etc....  ; depending on the  code of VeraCrypt it can need to be launched with spécific parameters to be able to access instance ...  Give more details please or buy a crystal ball :)

Comment: VeraCrypt is a GUI. With opening the running instance I was referring to showing the GUI so that I can use the program.

Comment: so you have to either run it from a window manager either with an export DISPLAY corresponding to a window manager & use  swith to the concerned window manager to see it.

Comment: `DISPLAY=:0 veracrypt` shows the same error in a message window and the error `QXcbClipboard::setMimeData: Cannot set X11 selection owner` in the console. Is that what you mean? I'm using KWin.

Comment: More or less the same problem is described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676989/how-to-circumvent-veracrypt-is-already-running