# How to circumvent "VeraCrypt is already running"

Tags: linux, encryption, veracrypt

I'm running VeraCrypt which looks something like this:

[image]

I can close this window and open it again by using the system tray icon. However, sometimes my X server crashes and after restarting it, the icon isn't there anymore. All the mounted volumes are still working fine though: VeraCrypt is still running in the background. So if I try to start it, I get:

[image]

How can I get back into the main window if I don't have a system tray icon?

Comment: FYI only -- https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/issues/461 and https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/issues/251. https://documentation.help/VeraCrypt/Command%20Line%20Usage.html also mentions the `/q background` option, which "launches the VeraCrypt Background Task (tray icon) unless it is disabled in the Preferences" (I can't test at the moment)

Comment: Have you found a solution? This also occurs for me Debian11/KDE. It means if the tray icon isn't showing anymore, I can't dis/mount volumes and I don't think killing the veracrypt process with the process manager and restarting it would be good for the volume. Maybe the solution or problem is related to KDE: are you using it or another DE?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I haven't found a solution. It's very weird. I'm using i3 and I don't even care about the tray icon. I just want a way to show the main window, but even that doesn't work haha. So currently I'm just dismounting everything via console and then reboot. :(